# SQL Developer ERROR: Reference to uninitialized collection

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

I am executing the below procedure from SQL DEVELPER, I get an option to insert the input values for `z_id`  & `i_type` however `i_data` is greyed out.

can a procedure with input param as collection cannot be executed from SQL
DEVELOPER tool ?

What am I missing here ? The code gets compiled but unable to execute it through SQL Developer

below is what I have done but this gives compilation error on Oracle 19c

```
create or replace type my_type AS OBJECT (
p_id number,
p_text varchar2 (100),
p_details clob);
/
create or replace type tab1 is table of my_type;
/



 create or replace procedure vehicle_det (z_id in varchar2, i_type in varchar2, i_data in tab1)
    IS
   BEGIN
    for i in 1..i_data.count
    LOOP
    if (i_type ='BMW')
    THEN
    UPDATE STOCK_DATA
    set stock_id=i_data(i).p_id, stock_des=i_data(i).p_text, clearance=i_data(i).p_details where s_id=z_id ;
    end if;
    end loop;
    end vehicle_det;
```

Below is the error, please provide your wisdom::::
**ERROR --ORA-06531 Reference to uninitialized collection **

Comment: The parameter `i_data` is of type `my_type` which is a scalar.  You can't iterate over a scalar.  My guess is that you intended `i_data` to be of type `tab1` which is a collection.  You can iterate over a collection.

Comment: @JustinCave thanks for the wisdom, updated the code in question gets complied but unable to execute it **ERROR --ORA-06531 Reference to uninitialized collection**

Comment: If you're getting an error when calling the code, please edit your question to include how you're calling the procedure.  My guess would be that you're not correctly initializing the collection before calling the procedure.

Comment: @JustinCave I am trying to execute the procedure from SQL Developer tool  have updated the question

Comment: @JustinCave, Don't you think OP is missing BEGIN keyword in the procedure definition.

Comment: it was a typo, my bad. code is updated

Comment: @WilliamRobertson m not sayin its a issue with sql developer tool , issue is procedure is compiled but unable to test it

Comment: Sorry, deleted my earlier comment to replace it with a more detailed one but missed that you had already replied. I wanted to add that "How are you calling the procedure?" means what code did you use to call it, not what tool do you have. `i_data in tab1` requires you to pass in an object of type `tab1`, which could cause problems, although it's totally doable in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that actually *works*. See how it is done.

Types and sample table:

```
SQL> create or replace type my_type AS OBJECT (
  2    p_id      number,
  3    p_text    varchar2 (100),
  4    p_details clob);
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type tab1 is table of my_type;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table stock_data
  2    (s_id       number,
  3     stock_id   number,
  4     stock_des  varchar2(20),
  5     clearance  clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into stock_data
  2    select 1 s_id, 1 stock_id, 'Description' stock_Des, null clearance
  3    from dual;

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure vehicle_det
  2    (z_id in varchar2, i_type in varchar2, i_data in tab1)
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5    for i in 1..i_data.count LOOP
  6      if i_type = 'BMW' THEN
  7         UPDATE STOCK_DATA
  8           set stock_id  = i_data(i).p_id,
  9               stock_des = i_data(i).p_text,
 10               clearance = i_data(i).p_details
 11           where s_id = z_id ;
 12      end if;
 13    end loop;
 14  end vehicle_det;
 15  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing: current table contents / run the procedure / see the result:

```
SQL> select * from stock_data;

      S_ID   STOCK_ID STOCK_DES            CLEARANCE
---------- ---------- -------------------- ------------------------------
         1          1 Description

SQL> declare
  2    l_data tab1 := tab1();
  3  begin
  4    l_data.extend;
  5    l_data(1) := my_type(1, 'This is BMW', 'Oh yes, this IS a BMW!');
  6
  7    vehicle_det(1, 'BMW', l_data);
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from stock_data;

      S_ID   STOCK_ID STOCK_DES            CLEARANCE
---------- ---------- -------------------- ------------------------------
         1          1 This is BMW          Oh yes, this IS a BMW!

SQL>
```

Comment: works like a charm @littlefoot thanks for assistance

Comment: is there a way i can write the below regex using dynamic sql ```regexp_replace(result_of_first_pass, '\.(docx|pdf|msg) ', '.\1, ')``` unable to escape all the characters when trying to write a dynamic sql

Comment: You should open a new question for a new problem. Please, do so, explain it properly.

Comment: yes I could have but I dont have enough credits to ask question, can you please assist for once @littlefoot

Comment: Huh? How come you opened your 3 previous questions, then? You don't have to have any *credits* to ask.